# Question about macOS's caffeinate utility

Tags: macos, sleep, computation

When one needs to run long-running computations on macOS, `caffeinate` utility is very handy.

However, it is not very clear from the documentation, which flags I suppose to use?

`man caffeinate` says:

```
-i      Create an assertion to prevent the system from idle sleeping.
-s      Create an assertion to prevent the system from sleeping. This
             assertion is valid only when system is running on AC power.
```

I struggle to see the difference. Could someone shed the light on this, please?

Comment: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (for Apple users) might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-i` flag uses the `PreventUserIdleSystemSleep` assertion status which prevents the entire system from idle sleeping, which is the default mode when no assertion flags are specified.

The `-s` flag uses the `PreventSystemSleep` assertion status, which is only valid when your device is connected to an AC power.

The core difference is that with `-i` flag, it prevents the kind of sleep that is activated when the user sits idle for a certain period of time, but does not prevent the system from sleeping when you (or something else) command it to. The `-s` flag, on the other hand, prevents the entire system from sleeping regardless, even when it's instructed to do so.

P.S. You can see the assertion type created by `caffeinate` using `pmset -g assertions | grep 'caffeinate'`.

Comment: Thank you! The manpage is a bit unclear in that regard but yes, I see via `pmset...` command that `caffeinate` and `caffeinate -i` create the same assertion. It also looks like `-s` assertion is stronger than `-i` assertion, although it is not clear wrt to battery power.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov yeah the manpage is written in a very simplified manner (a little too simplified), it’d be a lot more helpful if it at least told us the type of assertion each flag creates so that we don’t have to dig it up by using `pmset` just to see what each flag does.